# Where to post question about Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: discussion

As the title says: Is this the correct community to post questions about the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` Windows 10 feature?

It is kind of based on Ubuntu but I guess not enough and questions would probably be off topic on AskUbuntu and maybe even on Unix&Linux.

Where would you propose question about the Subsystem should go to?

Comment: If you asked the question be sure you indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using.  On Windows 1607 and 1703 Windows ...is labeled as being a beta, and the bash feature is called `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows`.  However, on Windows 10 1709+, `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` was retired on it's simply `Windows Subsystem for Linux`.  I don't find questions that are not clear to be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Super User is probably the most correct place, especially if you are asking about a feature that integrates with Windows.

If your question is about the use of generic commands that would work exactly the same on Linux as WSL then one of the other communities might be able to answer as well.

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking

We currently have around 240 questions regarding the [Windows subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux).

Comment: **computer software**, or << definitely this.